# FastMM NeverSleepOnThreadContention

Tags: delphi, fastmm

The documentation in the INC file is pretty scares about this option.

So, in which situation I get performance if I activate the NeverSleepOnThreadContention and UseSwitchToThread options in FastMM?
Should I activate them also for classic (non-multithreading) Delphi applications?

Or, to put it otherwise, where I should NOT activate this option?

Comment: [NeverSleepOnThreadContention–NOT!](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2011/09/neversleeponthreadcontentionnot.html).

Comment: This can be of interest too, [Memory Manager Investigations](http://www.delphitools.info/2011/10/13/memory-manager-investigations/). Generally I would say that Delphi could not have survived without FastMM. I really hope Pierre will have time to finish version 5 with a fully scalable memory manager.

Comment: Do you have a problem that needs to be solved? My experience with `NeverSleepOnThreadContention` is that it solves no problems. My advice for dealing with contention on the allocator is to remove the contention. Shun heap allocation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-No, no problem. I just have seen it in the INC file and I was curious about it.

Comment: @LURD-I think Embarcadero should help Pierre a bit (read is as 'a lot') because this piece of software is indeed critical for Delphi's future. While Embarcadero charges us quite a big pile of money (yeah... I have to upgrade soon to something that supports Mac and there is this big decision I have to make between upgrading my DelphiXE license or trying one more time to migrate to Lazarus), Pierre gets nothing from them.

Comment: @Altar I just use a different allocator which scales better. Easy to swap one in.